# No Button Visible Java

Tags: java

So when I try to run my code it works fine but I get given no button to click on.
I have solved the error I was getting from it but I don't understand why no button is coming up on my window.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Main () {
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Main Window");
    mainWindow.setSize(1200, 800);
    mainWindow.setTitle("Main Window");
    mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
    add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Main();
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Clicked");
    frame2.setVisible(true);
    frame2.setSize(200, 200);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("You Clicked Me!");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame2.add(panel);
    panel.add(label);
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for changing it Adbelhak didn't realise you were editing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `mainWindow.add(button);` to `JFrame mainWindow = ...` like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
mainWindow.add(button);
```

The block of the code should be:

```
public Main () {
   JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Main Window");
   mainWindow.setSize(1200, 800);
   mainWindow.setTitle("Main Window");
   mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   mainWindow.setVisible(true);

  JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
  mainWindow.add(button);
  button.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Take a look at this image:
[image]

Comment: Tried this doesn't work, could it be placed but not on screen?

Comment: I have I still get nothing but a white background.

Comment: @HenryMigo Is this really worked for you, or you just accepted it because there is no other answers?

Comment: @AleksandrM he doesn't obliged to accept my answer.